# Is there a function for finding the first non-null element in an xts

Tags: r, xts

I have a portfolio spanning ca. 20 years with daily prices and I want to compute returns for every year. Except that there is no data on dates 20xx-12-31 & 20xx-01-01. How can I get the previous & next valid data from the xts?

```
# create portfolio, no data on holidays
dates <- as.Date(c("2016-12-29","2017-01-02", "2017-12-30", "2018-01-03"))
portfolio <- as.xts(x = c(100000, 101000, 110000, 110500), order.by = dates)
```

What I hope for:

```
# expected result
portfolio["2017-01-01"]
2017-01-02   101000
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `library(lubridate);portfolio[as.Date("2017-01-01") + days(1)]`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, but that doesn't work for 2018, when there are 2 days before the next value.

Comment: Is the logic to get the value until there is one ?  Perhaps `portfolio[as.Date("2017-01-01") + days(1:5)]` and then select first row

Comment: yes, at least in the case of beginning of the year. I'm also looking to get the one before the end of the year.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, that workaround works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

I got 2 answers from @akrun and @FXQuantTrader.

Thanks to @akrun for the first answer.

you can get the next (or previous) n values and then select the first one (resp. last):

```
# the next values
values <- portfolio[as.Date("2016-01-01") + days(1:5)]
start_value <- values[1]
# the previous values
values <- portfolio[as.Date("2017-01-01") + days(-1:-5)]
end_value <- values[length(values)]
```

and thanks to @FXQuantTrader for pointing out the `endpoints` function

```
# get endpoints (sp is for start points)
ep <- endpoints(portfolio, on = "years")
sp <- ep[1:length(ep)-1] + 1
start_values <- portfolio[sp]
end_values <- portfolio[ep]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some `xts` tools that may help you solve your problem.

```
xx <- getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

If you want to generate annual returns (not clear in your question if you want to do this or not), you could simply use `annualReturn` (along with many other return frequencies, like `monthlyReturn()`)?

```
y <- annualReturn(xx)
y
```

If you're looking to get the first and last observations in each year, you can exploit the endpoints function (Which also works for other `on` values like seconds, minutes, days, weeks, months, etc)

```
ep <- endpoints(xx, on = "years")
```

Get the last bar in each year:

```
xx[ep,]

#            AAPL.Open AAPL.High  AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2007-12-31  28.50000  28.64286  28.25000   28.29714   134833300     18.868626
# 2008-12-31  12.28143  12.53429  12.19143   12.19286   151885300      8.130234
# 2009-12-31  30.44714  30.47857  30.08000   30.10429    88102700     20.073631
# 2010-12-31  46.13571  46.21143  45.90143   46.08000    48377000     30.726294
# 2011-12-30  57.64429  58.04000  57.64143   57.85714    44915500     38.579315
# 2012-12-31  72.93285  76.48572  72.71429   76.02428   164873100     53.974899
# 2013-12-31  79.16715  80.18285  79.14286   80.14571    55771100     67.919533
# 2014-12-31 112.82000 113.13000 110.21000  110.38000    41403400    102.503265
# 2015-12-31 107.01000 107.03000 104.82000  105.26000    40635300     99.414101
# 2016-12-30 116.65000 117.20000 115.43000  115.82000    30586300    111.821404
# 2017-12-29 170.52000 170.59000 169.22000  169.23000    25884400    166.014908
# 2018-12-31 158.53000 159.36000 156.48000  157.74000    35003500    157.066376
# 2019-04-29 204.39999 205.97000 203.86000  204.61000    22125400    204.610001
```

Get the first bar in each year is a little trickier, but easy once you know what `endpoints` returns

```
xx[ep[-length(ep)] + 1,]

#            AAPL.Open AAPL.High  AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03  12.32714  12.36857  11.70000   11.97143   309579900      7.982585
# 2008-01-02  28.46714  28.60857  27.50714   27.83429   269794700     18.559986
# 2009-01-02  12.26857  13.00571  12.16571   12.96429   186503800      8.644626
# 2010-01-04  30.49000  30.64286  30.34000   30.57286   123432400     20.386072
# 2011-01-03  46.52000  47.18000  46.40572   47.08143   111284600     31.394041
# 2012-01-03  58.48571  58.92857  58.42857   58.74714    75555200     39.172771
# 2013-01-02  79.11714  79.28571  77.37572   78.43285   140129500     55.684914
# 2014-01-02  79.38286  79.57571  78.86000   79.01857    58671200     66.964325
# 2015-01-02 111.39000 111.44000 107.35000  109.33000    53204600    101.528191
# 2016-01-04 102.61000 105.37000 102.00000  105.35000    67649400     99.499107
# 2017-01-03 115.80000 116.33000 114.76000  116.15000    28781900    112.140007
# 2018-01-02 170.16000 172.30000 169.26000  172.26000    25555900    168.987320
# 2019-01-02 154.89000 158.85001 154.23000  157.92000    37039700    157.245605
```

In `ep[-length(ep)] + 1`, the last value in `ep` returns the last observation index in the data set, so it is excluded.  We increment each `ep` value by 1 to get the first observation of the next 'interval' (which is a year here).

Also `ep[1] = 0`, so `ep[1] + 1` will return the first row in the data set.